# Сокращения "и т.д."

Tags: стилистика

Также хотелось бы уточнить насчет сокращений вроде "и т.д.", "и др.", "т.е." Уместны ли они в литературном тексте?

Comment: Интересно, а какой текст вы считаете "литературным"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наши классики использовали такие сокращение в литературных текстах.

Л.Н.Толстой. "Юность" - "Род человеческий можно разделять на множество отделов — на богатых и бедных, на добрых и злых, на военных и статских, на умных и глупых и т. д., и т. д., но у каждого человека есть непременно свое любимое главное подразделение, под которое он бессознательно подводит каждое новое лицо"

Но я бы поостерегся и писал полностью.

С другой стороны, сокращения больше подходят для технических текстов. Тем более, что там могут быть и специфические, незнакомые большинству, сокращения.

В деловой переписке допустимо использование стандартных (по сути - общеизвестных) сокращений.